# Filter one div with same class as others with jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, filter

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nFGRa/).
As you can see when a colour from the select drop down is selected *all* the divs with the class ".box" change colour.
 Is it possible to only change one div at a time, leaving the others as they are? There will be hundreds of these so changing the class/id of each one is not really an option.
I have tried a bunch of filters with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could provide a `context` for `$('.box')`, which is `$(this).parent()`.

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $('.box', $(this).parent()).removeClass('red green blue').addClass(
        $(this).find('option:selected').text().toLowerCase()
    );
})
.change();
```

Answer (score 1):

change your js code to this:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.box').removeClass('red green blue').addClass(
        $(this).find('option:selected').text().toLowerCase()
    );
})
.change();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.prev( selector )`](http://api.jquery.com/prev), in your example it would be:

```
$('select').change(function() {
  $(this).prev('.box').addClass();
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/nFGRa/2/